# Watir unable to find Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox

I am using Watir to crawl something, but it throw

```
Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it
```

I've done following step.

Downloading the latest firefox (version50.0)

I download the latest version of `geckodriver` from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases, and put it in `~/geckodriver`

Then add `export PATH=$PATH:~/geckodriver` into `~/.bash_profile` and source it.

Here is code I executed

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox # should open a new Firefox window
browser.goto 'http://nitrowriters.com/form/form.html' # or type the local path to your downloaded copy
```

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem  'nokogiri'
gem  'watir-webdriver'
gem  'open_uri_redirections'
gem  'selenium-webdriver'
gem  "watir", ">= 6.0.0.beta2"
```

Environment: OSX 10.10

Comment: Your steps actually worked for me on `Sierra 10.12.1`, `FF 50.1.0`, and `GeckoDriver 0.13.0`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint 17.2. I solved it by **moving** the `geckodriver` file from the extracted tar **to** `usr/bin` (you have to have root permission to do that).

For some reason zsh would not find it if I defined it in my `path` variable. Maybe someone else has a better solution, but for now this works.

Comment: @CodaChang
Try this in your shell:
`set -U fish_user_paths /path/to/your/gecko/driver $fish_user_paths`
It should permanently change your PATH.

Answer (score 3):

If geckodriver is in `~/`, just add `~/` to your path. Only directories should be in your path. It is probably looking for geckodriver in `~/geckodriver/geckodriver`

Also, if you're using the latest version of Watir (6), you just need to `require "watir"` instead of `require "watir-webdriver"`